# Ajax Long Poll ,PHP or Python which uses least Memory?

Tags: php, python

Which Language  would  be better  to implement  long ajax poll,
i  heard  php  uses  more  memory in  long ajax poll, is that correct?

Comment: Ok.Nice Clear  Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do long polling, go for Node.js It can handle thousands of requests on very low hardware config. If you know Python, you can use Tornado or Twister for long polling application.